# How does exporting symbols in .so libraries work with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, build, shared

this is more of a theoretical question, rather than a problem to solve.
I'm having some shared library, ex. library.so

I'm doing

```
add_library(library SHARED file1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(library PUBLIC somelib)
```

Then when i have that .so file after building i do:
nm -gDC library.so > symbols.txt

symbols.txt contains exported symbols from that .so file, now my question is what cmake code is responsible for exporting symbols to .so libraries?

- Is it add_library or target_link_libraries that exports the symbols? maybe both?
- Can i make it, somehow, so that the symbols are not exported from a cpp file or library by setting some kind of keyword?
- Are there any other cmake functions that can export symbols?

Comment: This is a function of your compiler and the code you write. `add_library` creates the shared library target in the first place.

Comment: Refer to the documentations of GCC, clang, MSVC, etc.

Comment: I can't really control the functions of the libraries that are not mine

Comment: The exports are from 3rd party libraries

Comment: When asked to create a library with `add_library`, CMake just calls the compiler/linker with appropriate parameters. You may inspect these parameters by running `make` with additional `V=1` option. If you want some specific exporting behavior, then you should first consult your compiler documentation whether this behavior is possible. If this behavior is possible with additional linker flag, then with CMake you could add it with e.g. `target_link_options` command.